# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined" for push notification

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Hi I'm very new to this.

[Here is my data tree on Firebase:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU01W.png)

I'm trying to access the newly created nodes under "sightings" and here is my cloud function code.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

exports.announceSighting = functions.database
    .ref('sightings/{sightingId}')
    .onCreate(event => {
        const sighting = event.data.val()
        sendNotification(sighting)
    })

function sendNotification(sighting) {
    const name = sighting.name

    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'New Sighting Available',
            body: 'Hi',
            // body: title + name,
            sound: 'default'
        }
    }
    console.log(payload)

const topic = "Sightings"
admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)

}
```

From my understanding, I'm listening to new nodes by `.ref('sightings/{sightingId}')` **sightingId** is what I've interpreted from a tutorial given the name of the parent is **sightings**, but I don't know what I should put here to indicate that I am looking for children under **sighting**

[This is the error I've been getting this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYchD.png)

Your help is greatly appreciaated.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't show images of text.  Copy the text into the question itself so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Also I think you are working with a very old tutorial.  The argument passed to the function is not an "event".  It's a snapshot.  I suggest starting with the documentation to learn how database triggers work. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Comment: See the upgrade guide here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events), you should use the snapshot to get the data of the created object like so:

```
exports.announceSighting = functions.database.ref('/sightings/{sightingId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      const sighting = snapshot.val();
      sendNotification(sighting)
    });
```